# How do I tell TM2 file browser not to show certain folders

Tags: textmate2

I already have a .tm_properties file that includes these lines:

```
excludeInFileChooser = "{$excludeInFileChooser,log,vendor,tmp,META-INF,.svn}"
excludeInBrowser = "{$excludeInBrowser,log,vendor,tmp,META-INF,.svn}"
excludeInFolderSearch = "{$excludeInFolderSearch,log,vendor,tmp,META-INF,.svn}"
```

Specifically, I don't want to see the META-INF and .svn folders.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything wrong with what you've got and `.svn` should be hidden by default so it might be worth checking you've not got "Show Hidden Items" checked in the File Browser gear menu.

As an added tip, if you want to exclude from everywhere it's generally easier to just use exclude instead of the three separate commands.

```
exclude = '{$exclude,log,vendor,tmp,META-INF,.svn}'
```

It's also worth checking that you've not done anything in your home folders `.tm_properties` file that is breaking a project specific `.tm_properties` file

Answer (score 1):

I see an option `excludeDirectoriesInBrowser` in my .tm_properties. I think you can use this one.

Also a more detailed list and explanation of properties that can be used in .tm_properties here:

https://gist.github.com/1478685

Comment: Thanks Jake. I added these two variations of the property but had no different result, even after restarting TM2:  

    excludeDirectoriesInBrowser = "{$excludeInFolderSearch,log,vendor,tmp,META-INF,.svn}"

    excludeDirectoriesInBrowser = "{META-INF,.svn}"`